# Conversion To Recursivein javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
function add(num) {
var a = num.toString().split('')
var b = 0;
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  b += Number(a[i])
}
  if(b.toString().split('').length == 1){
    return b
  }
  else{return add(b)}
}
document.write(add(73)+'<br>'); //7+3=10 | 1+0=1
document.write(add(9980)); //9+9+8+0=26 | 2+6=8
```

Please help me, i have a code, but i want to make recursive untuk this code, but i am stuck...Thank's for your respond

Comment: It...already is recursive.
You see how you are calling `add(b)` inside the `add` function? That is recursion.

Comment: This could be *reduced* to `function add(num) {num.toString().reduce((total, curr) => Number(total) + Number(curr))}`

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, i just think, recursive is without looping 'for' or 'while'... i new for javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you already have a recursion, you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for summing the digits and check the value instead of a string for calling the recursion or not.

```js
function add(num) {
    var s = num.toString().split('').reduce(function (a, b) { return a + +b; }, 0);
    return s > 9 ? add(s) : s;
}

console.log(add(73));
console.log(add(9980));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function add(num) {
  if(num < 10) { 
    return num;
  }
  var sum = 0;
  while(num !== 0) {
    sum += (num%10);
    num = parseInt(num/10);
  }
  return add(sum);
}
document.write(add(73)+'<br>'); //7+3=10 | 1+0=1
document.write(add(9980)); //9+9+8+0=26 | 2+6=8
```